# Let (X,d) a metric space. Is there a way to show that for $\epsilon>1$ $\left\{x\in X:d(x,y)<\epsilon \right\}\in\tau_{d'}$for $d'(x,y)=min(d(x,y),1)$

Tags: general-topology

Let (X,d) a metric space. Is there a way to show that for $\epsilon>1$$\left\{x\in X:d(x,y)<\epsilon \right\}\in\tau_{d'}$for $d'(x,y)=min(d(x,y),1)$

Topology beginner here...

Maybe it isn't possible and I have to come to the conclusion of the exercise with some other reasoning so...
So the question in my exercise is bigger:
We first have to show that $d'$ is a metric on X (done).
Then I have to prove that the topology associated to $d$ ($\tau_{d}$) is equivalent to the topology associated to $d'$ ($\tau_{d'}$). Hence, the goal is to prove: $\tau_{d}=\tau_{d'}$

"$\subseteq $": It's obvious.

"$\supseteq$": Let $\omega \in \tau_{d}$.
We have that $\omega$ is the union of sets of the form $B_{d}(x,\epsilon)=\left\{ y\in X: d(x,y)<\epsilon\right\}$
So I tried proving that $\forall x\in X$ and $\epsilon > 0: B_{x,\epsilon} \in \tau_{d'}$. (Maybe this is false but I don't see any other way of proving the equivalence between both topologies. Then it's clear that if $\epsilon \leq 1: B_{d}(x,\epsilon)=B_{d'}(x,\epsilon)$. The problem lies when $\epsilon >1$

Comment: Perhaps you could start by expliciting $B_{d'}(x,\epsilon)$ and the ask $\epsilon < 1$ when you decompose an arbitrary open set of $\tau_{d'}$ into open balls.

Answer (score 0):

If $O$ is in $\tau_d$ then let $x \in O$. There is some $r>0$ so that $B_d(x,r) \subseteq O$. Define $r'=\min(r,\frac34)$. Then $r'>0$, $r'\le \frac34 < 1$ and $r'\le r$ so that $B_d(x,r') \subseteq O$ as well.
But clearly $B_{d'}(x,r')=B_d(x,r')$ (the $d$-values are small so $d'(x,y) = d(x,y)$) and as $x$ is arbitrary in $O$, $O \in \tau_{d'}$ as well.

The other inclusion is similarly trivial so $\tau_d = \tau_{d'}$.

Comment: Your answers always motivating me . If you don't mind , i am just starting to following you on stack exchange for improving my knowledge time to time because many of your statements can't be find in books or anywhere , it's can be reproduce just by  millionaire experience.